# PayPal API to withdraw funds from PayPal to Bank account (Transfer funds from PayPal to Bank account)

Tags: api, paypal, transfer, paypal-nvp

Please note: This is a generic question and not something specific to only Indian PayPal  accounts. Looking for an API that does this.

I am looking for an API (preferably NVP API) which allows to transfer money to Bank account, which is ultimately withdrawing money from PayPal to Bank account.

Please direct me to the documentation if there exists an API for the same.

I am aware of the fact, that for Indian Business PayPal accounts, the auto-withdraw feature is enabled and the withdrawals are done automatically everyday.
I am a developer and few of our PayPal clients are looking for such a feature. One of them is from Israel.

**P.S. This is a generic question and not something specific to only Indian PayPal accounts. This is not a country specific PayPal query.
Looking for an API that does this.**

Please help me with this.

Awaiting a reply soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no API for this, and there also is no reason for such an API to exist.

Withdrawing money is done automatically everyday, as you mention, or it is done manually in https://www.paypal.com (try the https://www.paypal.com/wdfunds shortcut )

There is no need for any API.

Comment: Hi preston-phx, Do you work with PayPal? Or have you answered it based on your research? Just wanted to know, so that I can confirm this!
https://stackoverflow.com/users/2069605/preston-phx

Comment: You can reach out to https://www.paypal.com/mts with technical questions, or https://www.paypal.com/smarthelp/contact-us for other support questions